# What is the domain of $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3-x^2y+xy^2-y^3}{x-y}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a problem with finding the domain of:

$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^3-x^2y+xy^2-y^3}{x-y}$$

The confusing bit is, I have never dealt with finding the domain with two variables. So, how do I do such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fraction can be simplified into $$\frac{(x-y)(x^2+y^2)}{x-y}$$ The only way this function is undefined is if the denominator is $0$. So $x \neq y $ is the domain of the function.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much!